# Rails wrongly interpreting http method when adding new nested record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form with nested attributes fields, made with `form_with model:`

```
<%= form_with model: [ :admin, @event ], local: true, class: "event-form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :event_category_id %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-7'>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#<%= dom_id @event %>-pl-tab" aria-controls="pl" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Polska</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#<%= dom_id @event %>-en-tab" aria-controls="en" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Angielska</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane panel panel-default fade in active" id="<%= dom_id @event %>-pl-tab">
          <div class='panel-body'>
            <div class='checkbox'>
              <label>
                <%= form.check_box :pl_active, class: 'panel-activator' %>
                Aktywna
              </label>
            </div>
...
```

and in that form i'm using `fields_for` nested attributes:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
              <%= form.label :event_variants %>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-6 text-right'>
              <%=link_to 'Dodaj', new_admin_event_variant_path( event_id: @event, index: @event.event_variants.size ), id: "add-event-variant", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary', remote: true %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='panel-body event-variants sortable'>
          <%- @event.event_variants.each_with_index do |event_variant, index| %>
            <%= render partial: 'admin/event_variants/form', locals: { event_variant: event_variant, index: index } %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and a partial looks like:

```
<div id="event_variant-<%= index %>" class='panel panel-default'>
  <%= fields_for "event[event_variants_attributes][]", event_variant, child_index: index do |fields| %>
    <%= fields.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= fields.hidden_field :position %>
    <%= fields.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 variant-title'>
          <%= event_variant.pl_title || 'Nowy element' %>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 text-right'> 
          <label class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>
            <%= event_variant.image&.file.present?  ? 'Zmień zdjęcie' : 'Dodaj zdjęcie' %>
            <%= fields.file_field :image, style: 'display:none', class: 'add-image' %>
          </label>
          <div class='btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-variant'>Usuń</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='image-container' style="background-image:url('<%= event_variant.image&.file.present? ? event_variant.image.url : image_path('no-image-icon') %>')" >
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#event_variant-<%= index %>-pl-tab" aria-controls="pl" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Polska</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#event_variant-<%= index %>-en-tab" aria-controls="en" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Angielska</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane panel panel-default fade in active" id="event_variant-<%= index %>-pl-tab">
          <div class='panel-body'>
            <div class='checkbox'>
              <label>
                <%= fields.check_box :pl_active, class: 'panel-activator' %>
                Aktywna
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= fields.label :pl_title %>
              <%= fields.text_field :pl_title, class: 'form-control', disabled: !event_variant.pl_active %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= fields.label :pl_description %>
              <%= fields.text_field :pl_description, class: 'form-control', disabled: !event_variant.pl_active %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane panel panel-default fade" id="event_variant-<%= index %>-en-tab">
          <div class='panel-body'>
            <div class='checkbox'>
              <label>
                <%= fields.check_box :en_active, class: 'panel-activator' %>
                Aktywna
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= fields.label :en_title %>
              <%= fields.text_field :en_title, class: 'form-control', disabled: !event_variant.en_active %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= fields.label :en_subtitle %>
              <%= fields.text_field :en_description, class: 'form-control', disabled: !event_variant.en_active %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

thats attributes are `has_many` related with main model, so beside fields to edit each of nested model, I can click to render new `fields_for` partial to create nem nested record - common thing I guess:

```
<%=link_to 'Dodaj', new_admin_event_variant_path( event_id: @event, index: @event.event_variants.size ), id: "add-event-variant", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary', remote: true %>
```

going to:

```
def new
    @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
    @event_variant = @event.event_variants.build( pl_active: false, en_active: false )
    @index = params[:index]
  end
```

and rendering `js.erb`:

```
$('.event-variants').append("<%= j render( partial: 'form', locals: { event_variant: @event_variant, index: @index } ) %>")
```

the problem starts when i'm trying to edit main record. When I'm only changing values of fields, adding images, etc. no matter if in main or nested fields its working ok, sending PATCH, updating record and nested ones.

BUT:
when I'm trying to add new nested record, by those fields rendered via `js.erb`, form is send with POST instead of PATCH to route: `/events/:id` and of course its generating `RoutingError`:

```
Invalid or incomplete POST params
Started POST "/admin/events/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-16 11:19:11 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/admin/events/14"):
```

form attributes are not changing. HTML still looks like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form class="event-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/events/14" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Z3Uhd6EgZ+N16P5MKbqLDs3F1d94iEokD4O5q63V04q/ofFblB5sRCmEO2m+coHayDrQ/zDNVHSzfSzmDGrxog==">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="event[event_category_id]">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#event_14-pl-tab" aria-controls="pl" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Polska</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#event_14-en-tab" aria-controls="en" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wersja Angielska</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane panel panel-default fade in active" id="event_14-pl-tab">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input name="event[pl_active]" type="hidden" value="0">
                  <input class="panel-activator" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="event[pl_active]">
                Aktywna
                </label>
...
```

even with `_method` field set to PATCH
even if I manualy set a method in form_with by `method: @event.persisted? ? :patch : :post`

Everything works correctly when no new nested record.
And last but not least, I'm not changing anything via js `onSubmit` nor `onClick` when submitting.

Any ideas what could went wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: nope. just simple:
`POST http://localhost:3000/admin/events/14 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: can you copy the complete generated form html?

Comment: @arieljuod I can't because it's too long for StackOverflow post (nearly twice). But I can paste some part

Comment: you could use some service like pastebin and share the link

Comment: also, check this for that `Invalid or incomplete POST params` error https://thomasleecopeland.com/2018/08/12/invalid-or-incomplete-post-parameters.html. I suppose that's the cause of your problem, since the POST params has errors, the method=patch hidden param is not recogniced by rails. Also check the browser's network tab when you send the form and see if you see anything wrong there too.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when a form field wasn't valid.

```
name="blah[]" # this isn't valid
```

See [ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got Rack::QueryParser::Params) on ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433947/actioncontrollerbadrequest-invalid-request-parameters-expected-array-got-ra)

Putting a pry in this file helped me out
/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb

```
def method_override_param(req)
   binding.pry
   req.POST[METHOD_OVERRIDE_PARAM_KEY]
```