# ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got Rack::QueryParser::Params) on ajax post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm managing a javascript table with some filters. 
When I set a filter on the table the table makes an ajax call to the controller.

The problem is the way this javascript component make the call:

These are the form data

```
pagination[page]: 1
pagination[pages]: 1
pagination[perpage]: 10
pagination[total]: 0
sort[sort]: asc
sort[field]: RecordID
query[]: sdfsdf
query[Status]: 4
```

These are the encoded params

```
pagination%5Bpage%5D=1&pagination%5Bpages%5D=1&pagination%5Bperpage%5D=10&pagination%5Btotal%5D=0&sort%5Bsort%5D=asc&sort%5Bfield%5D=RecordID&query%5B%5D=sdfsdf&query%5BStatus%5D=4
```

When between parameters I have `query[]: sdfsdf` my server crash:

```
ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got Rack::QueryParser::Params) for param `query'):
```

Is there anything I can do or I must change the js component from the source?

Comment: `query[]: sdfsdd` must have a key like `query[full_text]: sdfsdf` then you should be able to get it in controller as `params[:query][:full_text]`

Comment: I know, so the only way is to modify the js